# Downloading and installing python modules on Android?

Tags: android, python, module

Is there a way to download and install python modules for Android?

I tried to copy the module-packages from a laptop to an Android device and then use Python's `setup.py` to install as root.

I got a error like:

```
9814 could not load needed library "libpython2.7.so" "for python" (load_library[1093]:    Library "libpython2.7.so" not found)CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE 255
```

and now I noticed that I get this error every time with super-user to start python

I have: qpython app and I can connect my Android phone with USB to my laptop.

Comment: What Python do you have on Android? Does that installation have a method for installing modules?

Comment: its the QPython App terminal emulator python 2.7 and (3 i think too):D        i can use just exit() and than its the terminal from android       any links for help would be nice if there is something on whau to use modules from internet